# Ubuntu launcher disappeared - can only see maps on desktop

Tags: launcher

My ubuntu launcher disappeared. I can only see one map 'code' on my desktop. I can open this map but can't close/minimize or expand the browser window.

How do I get my launcher back?

Tried a lot of things but nothing worked for me...

Cheers!

Comment: Adding screenshot, and explaining what you did will help you to get the answer quickly.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions and information, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a external drive o USB memory like system drive and this unit get disconnected the launcher and system menu bar will disappeard.